# How can I save a GeoDataFrame to disk in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, save, geopandas

I have an GeoDataFrame called `merged` and I'm having a very hard time saving it to disk.
`merged` is obtained through this loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox

city=gpd.read_file('C:/folder/city.json')
circ=[]

for i in (0, 1):
    graph = ox.graph_from_polygon(city.geometry[i])
    stat = ox.basic_stats(graph)
    circ.append(stat['circuity_avg'])

circ=pd.Series(circ)
merged=pd.concat([city, circ], axis=1)
```

I simply want to save `merged` to a file, as a json file or another format that preserves the geometry, so that I can then use the data in R. Here are the methods I've tried:

1.

```
merged.to_file('merged.json', driver='GeoJSON')
```

which gives

> **Attribute Error** 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Does anyone know why `merged` is classed as 'int' while it is a GeoDataFrame (that's what's indicated when I do `type(merged)`)?

2.

```
with open('x.geojson', 'w') as f:
        f.write(merged_short.to_json())
```

This creates a `x.geojson` file in my Jupyter Lab environment but it doesn't save it to disk. That's understandable since I don't specify a path to save to. However, I on't know how to add a path.

3.

```
merged.to_csv("C:/folder/merged.cs")
```

This works but, since the data is saved as csv, the geometry is not preserved.

4.

```
merged.to_json("C:/folder/merged.cs")
```

But that gives `ValueError: Unknown na method`.

I'm very surprised I haven't found a simple way to save GeoDataFrames to a file on my computer. Is there a simple method to save GeoDataFrames?

### Solution

```
with open('C:/folder/merged.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(merged_short.to_json())
```

Meaning I just needed to specify the full path.

Comment: regarding (2): `'x.geojson'` is a relative path. Did you try to provide an absolute path?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, thanks. I didn't understand how that function was working.

Comment: You can use `os.getpwd()` to figure out the current working directory of your interpreter relative to which the file should have been saved when you provided the relative path.

Comment: Your first option ``merged.to_file('merged.json', driver='GeoJSON')`` should in principle work, and if it doesn't, that sounds as a bug (or something might be wrong with the GeoDataFrame). Would it be possible to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @joris Unfortunately, I can't manage to make a GeoDataFrame from the list of polygons I have because they are not written in the correct way: they're written as `POLYGON ((4.64761 52.42199, 4.64724 52.42197, ...))` while they need to be written as `([[4.64761,52.42199],[4.64724, 52.42197],...])`, if I'm not mistaken. I can't make polygons from scratch because my function `ox.graph_from_polygon()` needs actual georeferenced polygons to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version 2 will save a file, but to a relative location. Try providing an absolute path:

```
with open('C:/folder/x.geojson', 'w') as f:
    f.write(merged_short.to_json())
```